# Is it possible to fill an empty space using flex-start?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I use flexbox and my flex items can be collapsed. If I use 'align-items: stretch', they won't be able to collapse. If I use 'flex-start', there is a lot of empty space. The problem is I don't know what to do with empty space when it's not collapsed. Is it possible to set the height of elements like the I use 'stretch'?

If not, what are the alternatives?

The logic looks like this: https://codepen.io/darius9171/pen/qyVERX

or:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('collapsed');
    });
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
.container .item {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3 - 1rem);
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container .item:nth-child(1) .body {
  height: 25px;
}
.container .item:nth-child(2) .body {
  height: 50px;
}
.container .item:nth-child(3) .body {
  height: 75px;
}
.container .item:nth-child(4) .body {
  height: 100px;
}
.container .item:nth-child(5) .body {
  height: 125px;
}
.container .item .body {
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .item.collapsed .body {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="header">Head 1</div>
    <div class="body">Body 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="header">Head 2</div>
    <div class="body">Body 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="header">Head 3</div>
    <div class="body">Body 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="header">Head 4</div>
    <div class="body">Body 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="header">Head 5</div>
    <div class="body">Body 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet seems to work just fine - what are you not happy with?

Comment: Because I need to fill the empty space.

img - [link](https://pp.userapi.com/c846522/v846522641/ae1db/vKsdDukJJbk.jpg)

Comment: What do you want to fill it with? Can you add an image of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: In the previous comment I attached a picture. In this picture I have red marked that I want to fill. I need all the elements to be equal to the height of the biggest one. Toggle align-elements: stretch to flex-start is not suitable because it is not transition-able.

In that picture 1 block has a height-43px, 2 block-68px, 3 block-93px;
I want when the body is not hidden, the height of all blocks is 93px, and when it is hidden, it takes the normal height.

Comment: While I was writing previous comment, I came up with the idea to use stretch, and at the same time to wrap all my elements in another div, to which I assigned: 
display: flex; 
flex-direction: column; 

To my elements added in class 'flex-grow: 1' when body is open, and 'flex-grow: 0' when body is hidden

https://codepen.io/darius9171/pen/rrYZZW